# how can i make an executable that connect to a mysql db?

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying to do a very simple program that take a name, and then insert into a data base. i am using netbeans, mySQL workbench and xampp.
the problem that i have is when i do the build, the executable dont insert the name. 
when i am working on netbeans, the program work fine. insert the name correctly without no errors.
how can i do to have a executable that insert the name into the db?

this is the code that i use to insert the name into the table.

public boolean guardar(String nombre){

```
 try{
        String consulta = "insert into cliente values ('"+ nombre +"')";

        this.smt.executeUpdate(consulta);//Ejecuto la consulta
        this.smt.close();
        return true;
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any Errors? What about the DB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Well if your code works in netbeans your code is probably not the problem. How did you build it and how do you run it? Plus when working with mysql statements and user input Always use prepared statements instead of string concatenation as its more secure

Comment: i just "clean and build" and then double click :S, i never done this before. i always work from the idle

Comment: Dubbel click what? Did it create a jar file? What build tool did you use? Is it a single file program with a main method? You can then first compile the file with javac which will create a.class file which you can run with java filename